# How to design GUI using c++ in Xcode iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I am very new to writing Objective-c in c++ Classes.
I am Using a tool to convert C++ code to run in `iOS`. So Now I have to design GUI in my `CPP` class using Objective-C . My Main class is in cPP. I tried changing it to .mm extension for making it as a Objective-C++ class.
I created a objective-c wrapper class for GUI.

While using that Objective-C wrapper class in .mm file, I'm getting

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386  error.

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

ld is for linker derivative. This message means there are some functions/libraries you use that are not available in the iOS Foundation. Following this line, there are usually much more information stating what symbols are missing. You will have to put them here so we can tell what is missing